# How to tell if my laptop has a hybrid hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I recently just purchased a ASUS laptop (model: s551LB-CJ150H). Under the device manager it only shows WDC WD10JPVX-80JC3T0. Although according to the laptop retailer it is equipped with a hybrid drive, I doubt if it is true since I don't see any partition for the SSD portion in My Computer window. If it is a hybrid drive how could I verify it? I am using window 8.1 64bit.

Comment: The drive in question is not a Hybrid SSD drive.  Here is the proof [WD10JPVX](http://www.amazon.com/Western-Digital-Drives-Notebook-WD10JPVX/dp/B00C9TEBJQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1400503990&sr=8-1&keywords=WD10JPVX) my guess is that your reading what information you were provided by ASUS incorrectly.

Comment: thanks the link was helpful in clearing my doubt about hybrid hard drive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a "hybrid drive" you would not be able to see the small 24GB cache in your device manager because the firmware on the HDD's controller uses/manages it for optimal performance.

Western Digital does not seem to produce any hybrid drives **[like these Seagates](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822178340)** at all.

They do however have a **[single-unit dual-drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822236642)** solution for people stuck with only one SATA port/HDD bay which is completely different from a hybrid drive.

Anyways, either your laptop was mis-labeled or Asus accidentally put the wrong drive in there. Call them up and tell them they screwed up.

---

**Update**

After looking at the website I am inclined to think that the marketing terms used were confusing when you bought the laptop.

On https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_VivoBook_S551LB/ they says things like:

> Driven by Super Hybrid Engine II technology

On the specs page: https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_VivoBook_S551LB/specifications/ there are 6 HDD options:

- 500GB HDD 5400 RPM
- 500GB HDD 5400 RPM With 24 G SSD
- 750GB HDD 5400 RPM
- 750GB HDD 5400 RPM With 24 G SSD
- **1TB HDD 5400 RPM <- You received this one**
- 1TB HDD 5400 RPM With 24 G SSD

---

**On an unrelated personal note:**

I cannot believe companies are still shipping 5400 rpm drives with laptops!

Comment: Just be glad the HDD makers stopped making 4200 RPM drives. In general, unless you pay specifically for a decent component, you will get the cheapest component a vendor can find. If they could find a good deal on 1 TB worth of floppy discs, they'd probably ship that.

Comment: @MSalters I would cry if I saw a 4200 RPM drive being shipped with a brand new laptop. I bought my first laptop in 2008 and I made absolutely sure that it came with a 7200 RPM. LMFAO at 1 TB of floppies!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explanation! Guess I was deceived by  the word hybrid HDD and didn't ask any further confirmation to the retailer while purchasing it.

Comment: @Boon Live and learn =) It's just unfortunate that certain learning experiences come with a price tag :/ but if you save enough money then the good news is that if you can access the HDD bay then you can certainly replace it with an SSD. Just make sure to measure the height in millimeters because there are slight variations and those variations can cause an SSD to not fit into a laptop's HDD bay. Good Luck!

Comment: well said and thanks :) it did cost me a small fortune (999aud) but so far I am still satisfied with the performance. On a side note, buying electronic products in Australia is notoriously expensive; unlike in US.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the drive manufacturer's website and read the specification.

http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=800

The spec for the WD10JPVX says nothing about being any SSD hybrid feature.